# Question regarding thermistors and ohmic heating

Tags: thermistor

[image]

I am unsure why these answers are so. My attempts were black, the correct answers were red. A test is coming up in 10 hrs so any feedback would be nice.

For Q9, I thought thermistors were made of semi-conductors and were more sensitive to heat than resistive thermometers. Thats why I though (A) was the right answer but it was incorrect...

For Q10, the function for a thermistor is that R(T) = Ro * e^(B*(1/T - 1/To))

If the temperature coefficient (the Beta symbol in the equation above) is negative, an increase in temperature will decrease the Resistance (e^-B is a decreasing slope function). Therefore, Lower thermistor resistance and (from here is me trying to understand it but failing to do so) lower Voltage out value? Meaning Higher temperature = lower voltage value so negative correlation???

I really am unsure.

Anyways any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Q9 = a very loaded question. A thermistor can have a positive temperature coefficient and hence answer (c) is only true for certain thermistors.

Comment: For Q10, look again at where Vout is measured. Your answer would be correct if you were measuring across the lower R - but you're not.

Comment: I would push back on Q9.  If it's a PTC thermistor, then (c) is wrong.